# if statement short-hand

Tags: c#, if-statement

If there a more concise way to write this type of statement:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c1))
{
    var _individual = new Individual { Age = Convert.ToInt32(c1) };
    request.Individuals.Add(_individual);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c2))
{
    var _individual = new Individual { Age = Convert.ToInt32(c2) };
    request.Individuals.Add(_individual);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c3))
{
    var _individual = new Individual { Age = Convert.ToInt32(c3) };
    request.Individuals.Add(_individual);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c4))
{
    var _individual = new Individual { Age = Convert.ToInt32(c4) };
    request.Individuals.Add(_individual);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c5))
{
    var _individual = new Individual { Age = Convert.ToInt32(c5) };
    request.Individuals.Add(_individual);
}
```

Comment: You could always add the values to an array and write a loop.

Comment: The fact that a string contains a value does not mean that that value represents an integer.  Perhaps you should consider using Int32.TryParse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach (var c in new[] {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5})
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c))
  {
    var _individual = new Individual { Age = Convert.ToInt32(c) };
    request.Individuals.Add(_individual);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Of course! Write a method:

```
private void AddIfAgeValid(string age) 
{    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(age))
    {
        var _individual = new Individual { Age = Convert.ToInt32(age) };
        request.Individuals.Add(_individual);
    }
}
```

Then just call it:

```
AddIfAgeValid(c1);
AddIfAgeValid(c2);
AddIfAgeValid(c3);
// ..
```

You may have to pass in `request` as well, not sure where you declared it.

You may also like to look into using an array or `List<string>` to store your ages, instead of `c1, c2, c3, ..` variables.

Comment: beat me 2 it. This is the better that the loops in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

```
foreach (var x in (new[] { c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 }).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))
    request.Individuals.Add(new Individual { Age = Convert.ToInt32(x) });
```

Or one-liner, if only `Individuals` supports `AddRange`:

```
request.Individuals.AddRange((new[] { c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 }).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(x => new Individual { Age = Convert.ToInt32(x) }));
```

**But I would not go that far. It's much less readable then `foreach`.**

Comment: Not sure if compound Linq statements are the best direction when they are trying to learn C#.

Comment: What makes you think OP tries to learn C#? I can see couple LINQ questions he asked before.